# Sharepoint 2016 How to change (ONLY) the Announcements webpart title font?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, 2016

I have 4 webparts on a site page in sharepoint. 3 of the webparts are a content editor and I added 1 announcements webpart. I was able to change the webpart titles of the content editor webparts, however I cannot seem to change the font color for the announcements webpart. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the announcements web part title is "Announcements", we can add the following style to a script editor web part to change the color of this web part title.

```
<style>
span[title='Announcements'] a{
    color:blue !important;
}
</style>
```

Or we can use this.

```
<style>
.ms-webpart-titleText a{
    color:blue !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For this you have add script Editor web part and add following snippet of code for CSS.

`.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText, .ms-webpart-titleText > a {
   color: darkblue;

   font-size: 18px;

   font-weight: bold;

   padding: 5px 5px;
}`